# Reading only the unread files in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a root directory where additional directories are being created daily or sometimes hourly, with avro files, example:

```
root/2021/12/01/file121.avro
root/2022/06/01/file611.avro
root/2022/06/01/file612.avro
root/2022/06/01/file613.avro
root/2022/06/03/file631.avro
root/2022/06/03/file632.avro
root/2022/06/05/file651.avro
root/2022/06/05/file652.avro
root/2022/06/05/file653.avro
```

Each time my PySpark code runs it needs to read the files that have not been read before in any of the sub-directories of the root. I need to process one file per run of the code. The code will be run about every 5 minutes.

How can this be accomplished, in PySpark?
Any approach/strategy and code ideas would be much appreciated.

Best :)

Michael

Comment: [This feature](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/sql-data-sources-generic-options.html#modification-time-path-filters) in Spark 3.+ may be not exactly what you want but could be of an alternative approach.